# Xaml intellisense not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, intellisense, designer

I have a problem with the intellisense. It works in code behind but not in xaml code (wpf).

[1st image: Intelissense not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4fUN.png)

[2nd image: I comment on the 1st usercontrol and the intellisense works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA8qF.png)

Here the code is in the usercontrol "cuAccessoiresAutres":

```
<UserControl x:Class="MicroSecu.ControleUtilisateur.cuAccessoiresAutres"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ControleUtilisateur="clr-namespace:MicroSecu.ControleUtilisateur"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="251" d:DesignWidth="672">
<UserControl.Resources>     
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="controlBorderBrush" Color="LightGray" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--En tête-->
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}"></Border>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Gauche" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1,2,2,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Droit" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
    </Border>


    <!--Profil porteur-->
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Profil porteur" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.ProfilPorteurGauche}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.ProfilPorteurGaucheEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1,1,2,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.ProfilPorteurDroit}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.ProfilPorteurDroitEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>


    <!--Anneau décalé-->
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Anneau décalé" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.AnneauDécaléGauche}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.AnneauDécaléGaucheEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1,1,2,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.AnneauDécaléDroit}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.AnneauDécaléDroitEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>


    <!--Glissière de reprise-->
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Glissière de reprise" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1,1,2,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.GlissièreDeReprise}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.GlissièreDeRepriseEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>

    <!--Glissière de reprise plateau arrière-->
    <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Glissière de reprise plateau arrière" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1,1,2,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.GlissièreDeReprisePlateauArrière}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.GlissièreDeReprisePlateauArrièreEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>


    <!--Tôle sur extensible-->
    <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Tôle sur extensible" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1,1,2,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.TôleSurExtensible}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.TôleSurExtensibleEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>


    <!--Plaque verte RMTCE-->
    <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Plaque verte RMTCE" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1,1,2,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.PlaqueVerteRMTCE}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.PlaqueVerteRMTCEEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>

    <!--Plaque jaune benne 1000L-->
    <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Plaque jaune benne 1000L" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1,1,2,2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding MaConsole.PlaqueJaune1000L}" IsEnabled="{Binding MaConsole.PlaqueJaune1000LEstDispo}"></CheckBox>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with code. Try to open an empty xaml file and see if intellisense works there.

Comment: Yes the xaml empty works. I have several usercontrol or the intelissense does not work and I do not know what it was due.

Comment: what version of visual studio do you use?

Comment: Did you restart VS? That usually fixes it for me.

Comment: Yes I have restart visual studio, same problem. Version of visual studio : 2012 update 5. At the time of generation, it sends me a message "xaml ui designer has stopped working" then an exception: "Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException"

Comment: My current version is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5

I downloaded a 2017 version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
Version 15.2 (26430.14) Release.

And I do not have the intellisense problem disappearing.